# Jquery camera in save mode does not save file

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using [jquery camera](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) in "save" mode, it seems to have no effect. I tried calling the url in "webcam.save" manually, it it worked fine. It seems that jquery camera is not working correctly. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ra/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ra/js/jquery.webcam/jquery.webcam.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1> 
<h4>Picture</h4>
<div id="picture"></div>

<input type="button" id="take_picture" value="Take Picture" />
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#picture").webcam({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        mode: "save",
        swffile: "http://localhost/ra/js/jquery.webcam/jscam.swf",
        onTick: function() {},
        onSave: function() {},
        onCapture: function() {},
        debug: function() {},
        onLoad: function() {}
});

$("#take_picture").click(function()
{
    webcam.save("http://localhost/ra/index.php/registration/do_upload_picture");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try removing your callback definitions (onTick, onSave, etc) since you are not using them, and define your debug method to output to the console and see if that provides anything useful messages.

Comment: Tried that and debug didn't provide anything on save.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call webcam.capture() before you call webcam.save(). Try adding webcam.capture(); in the line before your webcam.save line and it will work.